# (TypeError: friends.find is not a function) when running a spicific function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I created a function that enables the user to add a friend, but as soon as I press the Add Friend button, I get an error shown in the picture:

[image]

Once I add this code (marked with Error in the code below) under the line where I define the friends array
The error goes from friends.find It's not a function to friends.map It's not a function Which is in the friendsList.jsx component

Friends.jsx component code:

```
import { PersonAddOutlined, PersonRemoveOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { 
    Box,
    Divider,
    IconButton,
    Typography,
    useTheme
} from "@mui/material";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setFriends } from "state";
import FlexBetween from "./FlexBetween";
import UserImage from "./UserImage";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Friend = ({ friendId, name, subtitle, userPicturePath }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { _id } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
    const friends = useSelector((state) => state.user.friends);

    // if (!Array.isArray(friends)) {     |
    //     return console.log(friends);   |<=== Error
    // }                                  |

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    const { palette } = useTheme();
    const primaryLight = palette.primary.light;
    const primaryDark = palette.primary.dark;
    const main = palette.neutral.main;
    const medium = palette.neutral.medium;
    

    const isFriend = friends.find((friend) => friend._id === friendId);
    
    const patchFriend = async() => {
        const response = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:3001/users/${_id}/${friendId}`,
            {
                method: "PATCH",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
            }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        dispatch(setFriends({ friends: data }));
        // console.log("array123: ",Array.isArray(friends))
        // console.log("array123: ")

    };

    return (
        <FlexBetween>
            <FlexBetween gap="1rem">
                <UserImage image={userPicturePath} size="55px" />
                <Box
                onClick={() => {
                    navigate(`/profile/${friendId}`);
                    navigate(0); 
                }}
                >
                    <Typography
                    color={main}
                    variant="h5"
                    fontWeight="500"
                    sx={{
                        "&:hover": {
                            color: palette.primary.light,
                            cursor: "pointer"
                        }
                    }}
                    >
                        {name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography color={medium} fontSize="0.75rem">
                        {subtitle}
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </FlexBetween>
            <IconButton
            onClick={() => patchFriend()}
            sx={{ backgroundColor: primaryLight, p: "0.6rem" }}
            >
                {isFriend ? (
                    <PersonRemoveOutlined sx={{ color: primaryDark }} />
                ) : (
                    <PersonAddOutlined sx={{ color: primaryDark }} />
                )}
            </IconButton>
        </FlexBetween>
    )
};

export default Friend;
```

state.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    mode: "light",
    user: null,
    token: null,
    posts: [],
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setLogin: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.token = action.payload.token;
        },
        setLogout: (state) => {
            state.user = null;
            state.token = null;
        },
        setFriends: (state, action) => {
            if (state.user) {
                state.user.friends = action.payload.friends;
            } else {
                console.error("user friends is not exist")
            }
        },
        setPosts: (state, action) => {
            state.posts = action.payload.posts;
        },
        setPost: (state, action) => {
            const updatedPosts = state.posts.map((post) => {
                if (post._id === action.payload.post._id) return action.payload.post;
                return post;
            });
            state.posts = updatedPosts;
        },
    },
});

export const { setLogin, setLogout, setFriends, setPosts, setPost } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that *whatever* `state.user.friends` is that its `find` property isn't a function that can be called. In other words, `state.user.friends` isn't an array of object with a `find` property that is a function. When you `dispatch(setFriends({ friends: data }));` to update the `state.user.friends` state value, what is the value of `data` that is passed to the action/reducer?

Comment: Have you been able to verify the value & type of `data` that is saved into state?

Answer (score -2):

Below is the one way to get the `.find is not a function` error.

```
const arr = {};

// ⛔️ Uncaught TypeError: arr.find is not a function
const result = arr.find(num => num % 2 === 0);
```

Make sure `friends` is an array.
console.log it to check. It should not be anything else (str, boolean, number etc) than array.

Comment: If `state.user.friends` was null or undefined then the error would be "cannot access ... of null|undefined (reading 'find')" ***and not*** the error the OP has that lets us know `state.user.friends` ***is*** defined and it's just that whatever the `find` property is isn't a function that can be called. I don't believe your suggestion will resolve the OP's issue.

Comment: when i console.log it , 
it showing me it's an object

Comment: It should be an array according to what i defined it in UserSchema

Comment: ohh yea, that is the problem, it should be an array. Wherever you are changing or setting the `friends` variable, recheck all of those places. See if you are assigning an object instead of an array.

I think the issue is in `dispatch(setFriends({ friends: data }));`, check if data is coming as an array or object

Comment: @Rahul Saini I have written `console.log("the data is "+data)` under this line `dispatch(setFriends({ friends: data }));` , and this screenshot from the console 
[link](https://up6.cc/2023/10/169700934019441.png)